# Parse JSON inside Array Rails

Tags: arrays, ruby-on-rails, json, parsing

I have an array column in database in my Rails application. THis column stores array of hashes. But they are stored as string inside an array. I want to convert them back to array of hashes.

Database Column value. cards

```
 ["{:card_number=>\"12345678\", :card_pin=>\"12345\", :validity=>Sat, 01 Feb 2020, :amount=>100}", "{:card_number=>\"76355859\", :card_pin=>\"4532\", :validity=>Sat, 01 Feb 2020, :amount=>100}", "{:card_number=>\"76354858\", :card_pin=>nil, :validity=>Sat, 01 Feb 2020, :amount=>100}", "{:card_number=>\"76254859\", :card_pin=>nil, :validity=>Sat, 01 Feb 2020, :amount=>100}"]
```

I am trying to parse them and send array of hashes in response.

```
JSON.parse(cards[0])
```

gives

```
 JSON::ParserError (767: unexpected token at '{:card_number=>"12345678", :card_pin=>"12345", :validity=>Sat, 01 Feb 2020, :amount=>100}')
```

How can I convert this to array of hashes.

Comment: That is not json. Are you responsible for serializing the contents? This seems a simple `inspect` (converts the hash to string) ? Using `.to_json` would have been a lot better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I simply had to convert the hash to json before pushing it into the array and save it.

```
cards << { card_number: '123456', pin: '2345'}.to_json
```

Then while retrieving, I could simply do the following.

```
cards.map { |crd| JSON.parse(crd) }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is just stupid. Don't use array columns to store hashes. Array columns are a solution for special case scenarios when you want to store simple scalar types (strings, numbers) in an array. It should not be your goto "jam every kind of junk into" column type.

And even more importantly don't use arrays/hstore/json/jsonb to model data that should should have its own table. They are good for special cases where you have data that does not really fit into a fixed schema but should not be the default way to do anything.

Just by looking at that hash you can see that the data in fact has a pretty defined schema and can be very easily modelled with by just setting up a table and a one-to-many association. This will let you effectively query the data and gives you referential integrity.

Additionally saving card numbers and pin codes in plaintext is just irresponsible. If you have a database breach and the attackers get away with a large list of CC numbers you can be held liable.

Answer (score 0):

Not the full answer but this **date** value `:validity=>Sat, 01 Feb 202` should be escaped:
`:validity=>\"Sat, 01 Feb 2020\"`. Then you could just do `eval(cards[0])`.

But keep in mind that using `eval` can be a security hole, someone can execute malicious code.

Comment: eval has security hole. SO i cannot use it in my code. Any other option?